# Custom registration in Wordpress Page template

Tags: wordpress

I have a registration form in that some custom fields are there like phone, address, city, DOB, Zipcode I want to insert into wp_user table how can i achieve this..I am using **wp_insert_user** function

**Form:**

```
 <form  method="POST" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group vertical-line">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="row right-line-reg">
            <h4 class="reg-log-header">NEW CUSTOMERS</h4>
            <p class='log-register-text'>   By Creating on account with store,you will be able to move through the checkout process faster,<br>
                store multiple shipping 
                address,view and track your orders in your account and more
            </p>
            <div class="form-group row ">
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" class="reg-input-type" id="username" name="username"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                <label class="reg-label">EMAIL</label>
                    <input type="email" class="reg-input-type" id="email" name="email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" class="reg-input-type"  id="password"  name="password" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">CONFIRM PASSWORD</label>
                    <input type="password" class="reg-input-type" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"  />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">PHONE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="reg-input-type"  id="phone_number" name="phone_number" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">ADDRESS</label>
                    <input type="text" class="reg-input-type" id="address" name="address" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row ">
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">CITY</label>
                    <input type="text" class="reg-input-type" id="city" name="city"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">ZIPCODE</label>
                    <input type="text" class="reg-input-type"  id="zipcode" name="zipcode" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-6 remove-space">
                    <label class="reg-label">DATE OF BIRTH</label>
                    <div class="">
                    <input type="date" class="reg-input-type dob"  id="captcha" name="dob" />
                   </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-10">
                <button type="submit" name="task" value="register" class="reg-btn btn-primary btn-reg-log">Register</button>
             </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**DB Query**:

```
      $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['username']));
        $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));

        $pwd1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['password']));
        $pwd2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['confirm_password']));

        $phone_number = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['phone_number']));
        $address = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['address']));
        $city = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['city']));
        $zipcode = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['zipcode']));
        $dob = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['dob']));



      $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('user_login' =>
   apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_number' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_number', $phone_number), 'user_address' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_address', $address),'user_city' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_city', $city),'user_zipcode' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_zipcode', $zipcode), 'user_dob' =>    apply_filters('pre_user_user_dob', $dob), 'role' => 'subscriber'
 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$uam_user_id = wp_create_user(trim($_POST['username']), trim($_POST['password']), trim($_POST['email']));
    update_user_meta($uam_user_id, 'uphoneno', trim($_POST['phone_number']));
    update_user_meta($uam_user_id, 'uaddress', $_POST['address']);
    update_user_meta($uam_user_id, 'ucity', $_POST['city']);
    update_user_meta($uam_user_id, 'uzipcode', $_POST['zipcode']);
    update_user_meta($uam_user_id, 'udob', $_POST['dob']);
```

Copy and paste it then run it

Comment: Are you having problems? please do not hesitate you can ask me more